# Python выводит только кол-во строк в запросе MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

пытаюсь реализовать вывод всех названий позиций из таблицы MySQL

```
import pymysql
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             database='MyShop',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

cur = connection.cursor()

print(cur.execute('SELECT `name` FROM `positions_of_my_shop`'))
```

Код выводит только кол-во строк в данной таблице, но я хочу получить все названия позиций, которые содержатся в столбце name.

Comment: А что если сделать так?  (Так вы результат запроса в виде списка кортежей): print(cursor.fetchall())

Comment: @IaroslavLukianchik Спасибо помогло